# problem with writing a good awk begin header

Tags: awk, ascii

Is it possible to add something similar like this below but make it a variable, and {print var} and format it to be centered?

Also, I would like to make a solid line but I only get dashes ---- or _____ (_ does not produce a solid line in bash)

```
echo -n $'\E[31m'
echo $''
echo $'      _,.'
echo $'    ,` -.)'
echo $'   \'( _/\'-\\\\-.'
echo $'  /,|`--._,-^|          ,'
echo $'  \\_| |`-._/||          ,\'|'
echo $'    |  `-, / |         /  /'
echo $'    |     || |        /  /'
echo $'     `r-._||/   __   /  /'
echo $' __,-<_     )`-/  `./  /'
echo $'\'  \\   `---\'   \\   /  /'
echo $'    |           |./  /'
echo $'    /           //  /'
echo $'\\_/\' \\         |/  /'
echo $' |    |   _,^-\'/  /'
echo $' |    , ``  (\\/  /_'
echo $'  \\,.->._    \\X-=/^'
echo $'  (  /   `-._//^`'
echo $'   `Y-.____(__}'
echo $'    |     {__)'
echo $'          ()`'
```

I would like to use the BEGIN function and have this print title and ascii banner (centered) and have a solid line underneath it.

Comment: My sugestion would be to place this header in a file and just call this file using `BEGIN{system("cat headerfile")}`

Comment: Hey that does make it easier.

Comment: If you do print this from a file using `BEGIN{system("cat headerfile")}` you can't guarantee where in the output the header will be printed relative to the rest of the text (could come out before, after or half-way through it) so I wouldn't do that. If you wanted to guarantee where the text would appear relative to the rest of your output then you'd have to read it in a getline loop and print it, e.g. `while ( (getline line < "headerfile") > 0 ) print line; close(headerfile)`

Comment: thanks, I will keep this mind. I am going through the AWK Programming Language and trying to write compile my notes into a Index page within the terminal and then make END statment that runs system read with conditional statement based upon user input will take you to the respective notes page.. I have a lot of learning to do, trying to piecewise it together.